# converting javascript array to a dropdown - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to create dynamic dropdowns in which the values are changed based on the first dropdown.

Suppose I have a dropdown with three values namely `One`, `Two` and `Three`.

When I select `One`. I have a javascript array and that values in that array needs to be appeared as a second dropdown in the webpage.

Here's the <kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tcTwL/)</kbd>.

I have no idea where to start or how to start.

I googled and the result i got is creating a dropdown using `ul` not from a javascript array.

Any help will be very much helpful for me to overcome this.

Stuck for 2 days and I still didn't get any idea on how to do it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: this could be improved upon, but this should point you in the right direction http://jsfiddle.net/tcTwL/2/

Comment: @Crayon - Thanks a lot. That helped me out. Post that as answer please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this could be improved upon, but this should point you in the right direction. Here's the [js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tcTwL/2)

```
<script src='jquery.js'></script>

<select class="dropdown">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<select class="dropdown2">
</select>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dropdown2 = {
    1 : ['Four', 'Five', 'Six'],
    2 : ['Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine'],
    3 : ['Ten', 'Eleven', 'Twelve']
  }
  $('.dropdown').on('change',function() {
    $('.dropdown2').html(
      '<option>'+dropdown2[$(this).val()].join('</option><option>')+'</option>'
    );
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I wanted to add an value attribute with same values in the array. How do I do it? Tried concatinating the `data[$(this).val()].join()` by adding value attribute like this `'<option value="' + data[$(this).val()].join() + '">'`. But the result I got is `value='Four,Five,Six'`. Help me.

Answer (score 2):

http://jsfiddle.net/tcTwL/5/

```
var data = {
    one: ['Four', 'Five', 'Six'],
    two: ['Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine'],
    three: ['Ten', 'Eleven', 'Twelve']
}

$('.dropdown').change(function () {
  $('.dropdown2').remove();
  var newSel = $(this).after('<select class="dropdown2" />'); 
  var option = $('.dropdown').find(":selected").text();
  data[option.toLowerCase()].forEach(function(opt){$('.dropdown2').append('<option>' + opt + '</option>')});
})
```

Fairly straightforward. remove any older dropdown created, get the option value, and add new options. It's kinda verbose, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

#### Check this <kbd>**[demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uc3p5/)**</kbd>

#### jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var dropdown1 = {
        1 : ['Four', 'Five', 'Six'],
        2 : ['Seven', 'Eight', 'Nine'],
        3 : ['Ten', 'Eleven', 'Twelve']
    }
    $('.dropdown1').html(
            '<option>'+dropdown1[1].join('</option><option>')+'</option>'
        );
    $('.dropdown').on('change',function() {
        $('.dropdown1').html(
            '<option>'+dropdown1[$(this).val()].join('</option><option>')+'</option>'
        );
    });
});
```

#### HTML

```
<select class="dropdown">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
<select class="dropdown1">
```