# populating select menu options using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, select

Suppose there is a select menu like this:"

```
<select id="dropDown"></select>
```

And I wish to populate it with an array value `["apple","mango","banana"];`
How can this be achieved at one go without using any looping construct?

Comment: *without using any looping construct*. Why?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are avoiding using a loop to do this?

Comment: Is this even possible? Wouldn't all solutions at least have some implied "looping construct" under the hood?

Comment: @Zhihao: hardcode array indexes. `select.add(new option(array[0])); select.add(new option(array[1])); select.add(new option(array[2]));`

Comment: @Cerbrus Ah, of course. I hadn't even considered it, but lets hope it doesn't come to that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you can do [like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22753777/1671639)

```
var arr = ["apple", "mango", "banana"];
document.getElementById('dropdown').innerHTML =
    '<option>' + arr.join('</option><option>') + '</option>';
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9hq7w/)

Comment: `.join()` still uses a loop under the hood.

Comment: would there be any difference,while using very large arrays?(using/not using foreach or any loop)

Comment: @curiousUser first understand about the need of looping.. inorder to prevent code redundancy, so there will same performance in your case..so you can use any no. Of values in the array

Answer (score 3):

Without the use of a loop, you would do something like this:

```
var x = document.getElementById("dropDown");
var option = document.createElement("option");
option.innerHTML = "apple";
x.appendChild(option);

option = document.createElement("option");
option.innerHTML = "mango";
x.appendChild(option);

option = document.createElement("option");
option.innerHTML = "banana";
x.appendChild(option);
```

Obviously this assumes you know what the array values are going to be ahead of time.  The most common way of doing this however would be to use a loop to iterate over the array.

Comment: +1 since this is the __only__ answer that uses no loops whatsoever. Just fix the `.add()` and `.text` syntax, please, since that's not quite how DOM manipulation works (You can find the proper functions in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

If you just mean not using looping construct like `for`/`while`:

```
document.getElementById('dropDown').innerHTML = ["apple","mango","banana"].map(function(e) {
  return "<option>"+e+"</option>";
}).join('');
```

**[The demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/buCXT/)**

Comment: `.map()` and `.join()` still use loops under the hood.

Comment: @Cerbrus That's true and that's what i said at first, `looping construct`.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to do this:

```
var options = ["apple","mango","banana"],
    select = document.getElementById('dropDown');

for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++){
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = option.innerHTML = options[i];
    select.appendChild(option);
}
```

The "No loops" requirement is really a bad idea. This is the most efficient way to build the list, in native JS. (Aside from micro optimizations in the loop)

It also doesn't use `innerHTML` on DOM elements that are rendered already, avoiding the need for the browser to re-structure the entire DOM.

Comment: Could the person that downvoted my answer please explain why? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it. If it's because of the "loop" requirement: Keep in mind that a OP's requirements aren't always the best way to solve the issue, and most of the other answers are also using loops, disguised as other functions.